# Show that $\lVert f\rVert_1$ = $\int_{[a,b]} | f |$ is not equivalent to $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X = C[a,b]$.
a) Show that $\lVert f\rVert_1$ = $\int_{[a,b]} |f|$ is a norm

**I've done this part**

b) Show that the norm above is not equivalent to $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$.  That is, show that there are no constants $c_1, c_2 > 0$ such that $\forall f \in C[a,b], c_1 \lVert f \rVert_{1} \leq \lVert f \rVert_{$\infty} \leq c_2 \lVert f \rVert_{1}$.

Our definition of $\lVert f \rVert_\infty$ is $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \max\{|f(x)|\}$ for $x \in [a,b]$

I'm not really sure what to do here at all so at the very least I'd appreciate it if someone could just point me in the right direction

EDIT:  I would really love a full proof.  Even with all these hints I'm still confused

Comment: Find a sequence of functions, bounded in one norm, but unbounded in the other.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you give another hint?  I'm having trouble finding a sequence.  Would it be some sequence of intervals?

Comment: A sequence of elements of $X$.

Comment: Construct triangle functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$. We have that

$$\|f_n\|_1=\frac{1}{n+1}$$ and

$$\|f_n\|_{\infty}=1.$$

What can you conclude from the data above?

(Translate the result to $[a,b]).$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? the first one is unbounded, but the second is finite, but I don't know how to generalize this to [a,b]

Comment: To the proposer:  The sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges in the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm to the constantly-$0$ function but not in the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$  norm. Equivalent norms must have the same set of convergent sequences (with the same limits.)

Comment: Does there exist $C$ such that $\|f_n\|_{\infty}\le C \|f_n\|_1$ for all $n$? That is, does there exist $C$ such that $1\le \dfrac{C}{n+1}$ for all $n?$ To get the same result on $[a,b]$ consider $f_n(x)= \dfrac{(x-a)^n}{b^n}.$